# Confusion about useEffect Behavior

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array, react-hooks

I Just started to learn react and i'm confused about the nature of useEffect, according to the documentation every time i change or update a useState element the useEffect function will be triggered. But when i push a new element to my bombs matrix, why the useEffect i set up for the change of bombs matrix only render after the last iteration.

```
function Grid({heightApp, widthApp, handleEnd, end, handleBomb, numberOfCurrentBomb}){
  const height = heightApp;
  const width = widthApp;

  const currentGrid = Array(height).fill(Array(width).fill({
    isThisClicked : 0,
    isThisBomb : false,
    numberOfNeighboor: 0
  }));

  const [grid, setGrid] = useState(currentGrid);
  const [numberOfBomb, setNumberOfBomb] = useState(Math.floor(height * width / 10))
  const [bombs, setBombs] = useState([])
  const dx = [-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1];
  const dy = [-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1];

  function changeGridValue(numberOfClicked, clicked, bomb, rowId, columnId){
    setGrid(prev => {
      const newGrid = prev.map((row, i) => {
        if(i == rowId){
          return row.map((col, j) => {
            if(j == columnId) return {...col, isThisClicked : clicked, isThisBomb : bomb, numberOfNeighboor : numberOfClicked}
            else return col
          })
        }
        else return row
      })
      
      return newGrid
    })
  }

  function handleClick(e, rowId, columnId){
    if(end != "play"){
      if(end == "replay" && grid[rowId][columnId].isThisBomb == false) handleEnd("play")
      else{
        handleEnd("Lose")
        return
      }
    }

    if(grid[rowId][columnId].isThisClicked == 0 || grid[rowId][columnId].isThisClicked == 4){
      changeGridValue(
        grid[rowId][columnId].numberOfNeighboor,
        1,
        grid[rowId][columnId].isThisBomb,
        rowId, 
        columnId);
      
      if(grid[rowId][columnId].numberOfNeighboor == 0){
        const zeroArea = []
        const visited = [] 

        zeroArea.push({x: rowId, y: columnId})
        visited.push(rowId.toString() + " " + columnId.toString());
        let index = 0

        while(index < zeroArea.length){
          if(grid[zeroArea[index].x][zeroArea[index].y].numberOfNeighboor == 0){
            for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++){
              let xx = zeroArea[index].x + dx[i];
              let yy = zeroArea[index].y + dy[i];
              if(xx < 0 || xx >= height || yy < 0 || yy >= width) continue
              if(visited.includes(xx.toString() + " " + yy.toString()) || grid[xx][yy].isThisBomb) continue
              
              zeroArea.push({x: xx, y: yy});
              visited.push(xx.toString() + " " + yy.toString())
            }
          }
          index++;
        }
        zeroArea.map(area => {
          changeGridValue(
            grid[area.x][area.y].numberOfNeighboor, 
            1,
            grid[area.x][area.y].isThisBomb,             
            area.x,
            area.y
          )
        })
      }  
    }

    if(grid[rowId][columnId].isThisBomb == true && grid[rowId][columnId].isThisClicked != 2){
      handleEnd("Lose")
    }
  }

  function handleContextMenu(e, rowId, columnId){
    e.preventDefault()
    let value = 0
    if(grid[rowId][columnId].isThisClicked == 0 || grid[rowId][columnId].isThisClicked == 4) value += 2

    if(value == 2 && numberOfCurrentBomb == 0) return
    if(grid[rowId][columnId].isThisClicked == 1) return
    changeGridValue(
      grid[rowId][columnId].numberOfNeighboor,
      value,
      grid[rowId][columnId].isThisBomb,
      rowId,
      columnId
    )
    
    handleBomb(value == 0 ? 1 : -1);
  }

  function handleEnter(e, rowId, columnId){
    if(grid[rowId][columnId].isThisClicked != 0) return
    changeGridValue(
      grid[rowId][columnId].numberOfNeighboor,
      4,
      grid[rowId][columnId].isThisBomb,
      rowId, 
      columnId
    )
  }

  function handleLeave(e, rowId, columnId){
    if(grid[rowId][columnId].isThisClicked != 4) return
    changeGridValue(
      grid[rowId][columnId].numberOfNeighboor,
      0,
      grid[rowId][columnId].isThisBomb,
      rowId, 
      columnId
    )
  }
  
  // function createGrid(){  
    
  // }

  useEffect(() => {
    let cur = 0, bombsFound = 0;
    grid.map(row => {
      row.map(col => {
        if(col.isThisBomb == false && col.isThisClicked == 0) cur++;
        if(col.isThisBomb == true) bombsFound++
      })
    })

    if(cur == 0){
      handleEnd("Win");
    }
  }, [grid])

  useEffect(() => {
    setGrid(prev => {
      const newGrid = prev.map((row, i) => {
        const newRow = row.map((col, j) => {
          let bombsFound = 0;
          for(let k = 0; k < 8; k++){
            let x = i + dx[k]
            let y = j + dy[k]

            if(x < 0 || x >= height || y < 0 || y >= width) continue
            bombsFound += (grid[x][y].isThisBomb == true ? 1 : 0)
          }

          if(grid[i][j].isThisBomb) numberOfCurrentBomb += bombsFound;
          return {...col, numberOfNeighboor : (grid[i][j].isThisBomb ? "B" : bombsFound)}
        })
        return newRow
      })
      return newGrid
    })
    console.log(bombs)
  }, [bombs])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(end == "replay"){
      setGrid(prev => {
        const newGrid = prev.map(row => {
          const newRow = row.map(col => {
            return {...col, isThisBomb : false, isThisClicked : 0, numberOfNeighboor : 0}
          })
          return newRow
        })
        return newGrid
      })
      setBombs(prev => [])

      function randomNumber(maximum){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * maximum) ;
      }

      for(let i = 0; i < numberOfBomb; i++){
        let x = randomNumber(height), y = randomNumber(width);
        while(grid[x][y].isThisBomb == true){
          x = randomNumber(height), y = randomNumber(width);
        }
        console.log(i, bombs)
        setBombs(bombs => [...bombs, {x, y}]) 
        changeGridValue(
          grid[x][y].numberOfNeighboor,
          0,
          true,
          x,
          y
        )
      } 
      handleBomb(numberOfBomb)
    }
  }, [end])

  return(
    <div id="grid" className='d-flex flex-column'>
      {
        grid.map((row, rI) => 
          <div className="d-flex flex-row" key={rI.toString()}>
            {row.map((square, cI) => 
              <div 
                className="square"
                style={{backgroundColor : (square.isThisClicked > 0 ? ((square.isThisClicked == 1 || square.isThisClicked == 4) ? "#FDFEFE" : "#E6B0AA") :"#ABEBC6")}} 
                key={cI.toString()} 
                onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, rI, cI)}
                onContextMenu={(e) => handleContextMenu(e, rI, cI)}
                onMouseEnter={(e) => handleEnter(e, rI, cI)}
                onMouseLeave={(e) => handleLeave(e, rI, cI)}
                >{square.isThisClicked == 1 ? (square.numberOfNeighboor == 0 ? null : square.numberOfNeighboor) : null}</div>
            )}
          </div>
        )
      } 
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you use `useEffect` here. After manipulating the `grid` value in your `handleEnter` (etc) functions, you could just also execute the code that you now have inside `useEffect`. Then you call `setGrid` to update the new state. A workaround could be to pass all the individual properties that can change (`[grid.property]`) to the `useEffect` dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> every time I change or update a `useState` element the `useEffect`
> function will be triggered

This is not entirely true. If you call your setter (in your case `setBombs`) multiple times during the same render cycle, React will:

- Put all your updater functions in a queue
- Trigger a re-render
- During the new render, all your updater functions are called in the same order
- Only then, your `useEffect` dependency (`bombs`) has changed, so your effect is triggered.

In your case, you are calling `setBombs` within a for loop. Only after iteration has finished, React will re-render and trigger your effect **only once**, as explained before.

This is all explained in [React documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state).